# Issue with API key verification

Tags: javascript

Having this issue which is quite intricate from STRIPE. I'm also new to full stack. Firstly, i'm receiving this error in my console network.

```
raw: {,…}
headers: {server: "nginx", date: "Thu, 02 Dec 2021 12:21:48 GMT", content-type: "application/json",…}
message: "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/."
statusCode: 401
type: "invalid_request_error"
rawType: "invalid_request_error"
statusCode: 401
type: "StripeAuthenticationError"
```

Weirdly, I can confirm that Stripe is making post requests, in fact I can see logs going to them in my account dashboard.

This is being established through the following.
I set the stripeToken from the onclick, and then use a useEffect to create a post request to my endpoint. This should re-route to the success page afterward.

```
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  const onToken = (token) => {
    setStripeToken(token);
  };

  console.log(stripeToken)

  useEffect(()=> {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try{
        const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
          tokenId: stripeToken, 
          amount: cart.total * 100,
        })
        history.push("/success", {data:res.data});
      }catch{}
    }
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  }, [stripeToken, cart.total, history])
```

Furthermore, userRequest comes from the following, and this is where I think my error is. I am using my TOKEN from the login header when a user is logged in. and the URL of my port

```
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/"
const TOKEN = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYxOTM4MTE2ZGUxMjBiNmQzZGVmOWU1NyIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTYzODQ0NjkyNSwiZXhwIjoxNjM4NzA2MTI1fQ.ZsozvCvkc3ewlbwjKRceERsGBVF79zEHCZvbqFZBxJg";

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${TOKEN}` }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change code in stripe.js in backend

const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_****')

Answer (score 0):

In your api index.js, you need to move `dotenv.config();` above the lines that need .env variable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30776829)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, however i resolved it by adding few lines of code in my stripe.js file in the API

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Stripe = require("stripe");
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config();
const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY_MY);

router.post("/payment", async (req, res) => {
  try {
// Convert the token into a Source
const source = await stripe.sources.create({
  type: 'card',
  token: req.body.tokenId,
});

// Now use the source in the paymentIntent
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  source: source.id,
  amount: req.body.amount,
  currency: "usd",
});

res.status(200).json(paymentIntent);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while processing the payment.'});
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer questions on [so], if you'd be able to explain your answer with some more details I think it would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).